# Create a name system to html Id attibute so they do not repeat

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure if I make sense, maybe there are easier ways.

I am building a web app, which will be based in Bootstrap models, what I want is to display a model to make CRUD operations to my database.

For example I will have a models like these:

```
public class Author
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to make a partial view that will display a dialog (modal) to add a new author to my app, same with books, and my 'n' classes my app will have, I want to render these partials wherever I need them. So I can add an author from any view of my page.

That part is ok, now I am having some 'troubles' because when I make an ajax post call to save my author in my data base I am facing that I already had a #Name field which was the one rendered for my books modal now when I call my field with jQuery, like this: `$('#Name').val()` it will grab the first #name.

That is easy to solve I will make a #AuthorName and a #BookName.

Now I am scared that my application will not be stable if my name system is not.

So is there any way to make an name system?

I am not sure how to do this but I would like to write my id's like this:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Id, new { @id = "@MyDialogs.Authors.Add.Name" })
```

that will return something like this: `dialogs-authors-add-namefield`

Is this possible or I am being too lazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that, but I don't think it makes a lot of sense - it will be difficult to maintain. You'll have to create this external listing of names which no less likely to have errors than if you just name things better.

Instead, consider rewriting your javascript to be more 'closed'. Instead of using global searches like `$('#Name')`, scope it to the partial view.

For example, if your partial view looks something like this:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' id='Name' name='Name' />
    // ... other stuff ...
    <input id='add-book' type='button' value='Add' />
</form>
```

Then your javascript could look something like

```
$('#add-book').click(function () {
    var name = $(this).closest('form').find('#name').val();
    // ... do something with the name ...
});
```

That way it doesn't matter what else is on the form, it doesn't matter if you have name collisions, it's usable *anywhere*.